# Is it valid to use "setf" to create special variables?

Tags: common-lisp

It appears that I can use `setf` to create special variables. For example, if I start the REPL and enter `(setf x 123)`, a special variable `x` will be created. There is no error in CLISP and ECL. SBCL gives a warning (`undefined variable: COMMON-LISP-USER::X`), but creates the special variable anyway. Is `setf` a valid way to create special variables?

Comment: how do you know that it creates a special variable?

Comment: in CLISP, `(describe 'a)` indicates whether `'a` is special or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not valid to use `setf` to create new variables. The HyperSpec is pretty clear that `setf` is [only intended to update existing variables](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_setf_.htm):

> `setf` changes the value of `place` to be `newvalue`.

> `(setf place newvalue)` expands into an update form that stores the result of evaluating `newvalue` into the location referred to by `place`.

`setf` is intended for updating a place. There is no behavior specified for attempting to use `setf` to update the value of a place that does not already exist.

In the section which discusses assignment, [CLTL2](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node79.html#SECTION001112000000000000000) says a bit more:

> Such alteration is different from establishing a new binding. Constructs for establishing new bindings of variables are described in section 7.5.

While this may seem to work, you can't rely on it. It often works in REPLs, and it is fine if you want to use `setf` this way when playing around in a REPL, but you should not do this in any program.

Answer (score 2):

**Actually it is a bit tricky.**

This is one of the things in Common Lisp which are underspecified. Unfortunately.

LispWorks:

```
CL-USER 61 > (setf foo 1)
1

CL-USER 62 > (defun bar () foo)
BAR

CL-USER 63 > (bar)
1

CL-USER 64 > (let ((foo 2))
               (bar))
1
```

The last `foo` in the `let` is using lexical binding and thus there it is not assumed to be special.

In the forms `(setf foo 1)` and `(defun bar () foo)` the variable `foo` is **assumed** by the particular Lisp implementation to be special and it even could be declared to be special by `setf` (-> which most implementations don't).

Whether above `let` form returns `1` or `2` is unspecified in the Common Lisp language standard. Most implementations will return `1`, though.

Next:

```
CL-USER 65 > (let ((foo 2))
               (declare (special foo))
               (bar))
2
```

Above we see that the use of `foo` inside `bar` is actually using the dynamic binding of `foo` in the `let`.

Basically the exact effects of setting an undefined variable is unspecified. The variable could be assumed to be special or not. Most implementations prefer to **NOT** *declare* it *special*, such that further use of the variable must be special.

But whether the variable is *special* or not, and the exact effects using it, is actually undefined in the Common Lisp language standard.

Most implementations agree

1. that `setf` setting an undefined variable only changes the symbol value of the symbol
2. that setting and retrieving the variable is assuming a special variable
3. that rebinding the variable by `let`(or similar) does **not** create a special variable
4. that a compiler (if used) will warn about an undefined variable and/or about assuming a special variable.

One implementation where the default disagrees is CMUCL -> there the `setf` also declares the variable to be special, similar to what `defparameter` would do.

For a general style rule see the last paragraph of *ad absurdum*'s answer.

Comment: I can't understand your answer. to me, your code snippet shows that both `foo`s are lexical. not dynamic / special.

Comment: @WillNess  sorry, I wasn't finished editing. Please check again, is that clearer?

Comment: it's still a bit hard to follow. perhaps there's too much material to cover and it's too messy by its nature.

Comment: That's a good example.

Comment: so in the first `let` the global `foo` behaves as if lexical, unaffected  by the local lexical `foo` (unrelated to the global one). and in the second `let`, with the `special` declaration, the same global `foo` behaves as if it were special! this is just too strange. (I confirmed the same behavior happens in CLISP).