# "undefined variable: COMMON-LISP-USER::PRIMELIST" warning, using SBCL

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

Though I have been using Common Lisp on Linux for a while, my experience with SBCL is extremely limited.

And my experience with SBCL on Mac is equal to nothing.

I just installed SBCL on Mac (Sonoma 14.2.1) using homebrew.

I now have : SBCL 2.4.1

I am hitting a first problem when trying to use a separate file to include functions.

As a first test I have this file (test1):

```
   % cat test1
  #!/opt/homebrew/bin/sbcl --script

  (format t "Hello Lisp World !~%")
   %
```

which works as expected:

```
   % ./test1
  Hello Lisp World !
   %
```

Next I want to include functions from a separate file:

```
   % cat test2 
  #!/opt/homebrew/bin/sbcl --script

  (load "testInc")

  (format t "Hello Lisp World !~%")
  (outFunc)
   %
```

And testInc is as follow:

```
   % cat testInc 
  (defun outFunc()
    (format t "Hello Lisp Library !~%")
    (format t " From testInc.~%"))
   %
```

At this point things still work as expected:

```
   % ./test2    
  Hello Lisp World !
  Hello Lisp Library !
    From testInc.
   %
```

Things go wrong with my third test. I now change the testInc file to:

```
   % cat testInc
  (setq PrimeList '((2 1) (3 2)))

  (defun outFunc()
    (format t "Hello Lisp Library !~%")
    (format t " From testInc.~%")
    (format t "P1: ~a.~%" (car (car PrimeList)))
  ) ; End of outFunc.
   %
```

When I now try to run test2 I hit problems.
Like this:

```
   % ./test2     

  ; file: /.../testInc
  ; in: SETQ PRIMELIST
  ;     (SETQ PRIMELIST '((2 1) (3 2)))
  ; 
  ; caught WARNING:
  ;   undefined variable: COMMON-LISP-USER::PRIMELIST
  ; 
  ; compilation unit finished
  ;   Undefined variable:
  ;     PRIMELIST
  ;   caught 1 WARNING condition

  ; file: /.../testInc
  ; in: DEFUN OUTFUNC
  ;     (CAR PRIMELIST)
  ; 
  ; caught WARNING:
  ;   undefined variable: COMMON-LISP-USER::PRIMELIST
  ; 
  ; compilation unit finished
  ;   Undefined variable:
  ;     PRIMELIST
  ;   caught 1 WARNING condition
  Hello Lisp World !
  Hello Lisp Library !
    From testInc.
  P1: 2.
    %
```

One can see that the expected last line is showing up. And this code has no problem when used with common lisp (on Debian). Why am I getting the issue (WARNING):

```
  ;   undefined variable: COMMON-LISP-USER::PRIMELIST
```

How should I write the code to avoid this kind of warning ?

So I hope somebody with a knowledge of SBCL will be able to give me a hint on how to keep SBCL happy.

Comment: Use [`defvar` or `defparameter`](https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpar.htm) to define top-level variables.

Comment: The most interesting here is to know why your Lisp implementation on Debian does not warn you the same.

Comment: @JérômeRadix OP appears to be conflating Common Lisp (the language) with GNU clisp (The implementation). I installed it and it doesn't give a warning. Neither does ccl.

Comment: Yes that may be a good question. Since I did not know it was supposed to give me a warning, I never thought about that before. It looks like setf is interpreted slightly differently in both cases.

Comment: [There is no defined behavior for using `setf`/`setq` to create new variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69322022/is-it-valid-to-use-setf-to-create-special-variables) This often _will_ work, at least in the REPL, but you shouldn't rely on it and it certainly isn't portable. SBCL is fairly pedantic, so it issues warnings for this. Other implementations, e.g., Clisp, may be less strict. A lot of books seem to use `setf` to create variables in REPL interactions, and I think that this confuses a lot of learners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a variable before declaring it. You can use `defvar` or `defparameter` to declare it.

```
(defparameter PrimeList '((2 1) (3 2)))
```

Keep in mind that these will not be lexical variables, they will be dynamicly bound.

Most of the time it is better to keep passing additional variable.

If you don't want a global variable always available, you can still do this:

```
(let ((prime-list '((2 1) (3 2))))
  (defun some-func ()
    (format t "~A~%" prime-list)))
```

While this `(let (state-var ...) (defun ...) (defun ...) ... )` will be useful to share a state between several functions, without a visible state it can be a source for tricky bugs.

There is `defconstant` for global constants, if you never want to set it again.

Comment: Indeed. Replacing my setq by defparameter works. What then is wrong with setq ? You write : "You are using a variable before declaring it.", but isn't setq making some kind of declaration in itself.

Comment: But it still has to warn you, it could have been a spelling mistake or you are using a lexical variable out of it's scope.

Comment: @Michel: If you want to introduce a variable, `setq` is not the way to go. You should use `let` or some other binding forms.

Comment: I see, since I never had a problem on linux with common lisp I thought it was OK.
Thank you for the advice.

Comment: @Michel SBCL gives the same warning on linux...

Comment: @Shawn. Yes, maybe. As i wrote in my post, I have mostly been using CLISP there; and I never saw this before. For SBCL you must be right. It seems like CLISP is less strict and takes some default assumption that SBCL does not.

Comment: I fail to see why one would use the LET...

Comment: @RainerJoswig do you mean, why use `(let ... (defun ...` instead of `(defun ... (let ...`?

Comment: Yeah, the LET around the DEFUN usually makes no sense and is a bug magnet.

Comment: I agree `let` around a single `defun` is rarely a good decision, but `let` with multiple functions in it, is a good way to share a state. I found it particularly useful in this context, where some functions just use prime numbers available and others grow the primelist to the required size. good amortized performance.